# 404 on link to edit contact with contact hash

Tags: contacts, profile

I'm testing the ability to send emails out with a link for each contact to edit their own information anonymously, using the contact hash token as described in [Linking Profiles](https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Linking+Profiles#LinkingProfiles-LinkingtoBuilt-inContactViewandEditPage(s)).

I am able to access the profile anonymously, but when I click on the link provided in the email:
as with tokens: http://[site]/civicrm/profile/edit?reset=1&gid=36&id={contact.contact_id}&{contact.checksum}
in sent email: http://[site]/civicrm/profile/edit?reset=1&gid=36&id=[CID#]&cs=[checksum#]
I get a 404 error.

I've confirmed the URL based on the wiki documentation.
I've tried updating Joomla permissions (Public users are allowed access to profile listing and forms, profile create, profile edit, and profile view).
I've confirmed that my profile does not use any non-contact fields.

What should I check next?

Joomla 3.6, Civi 4.7.12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tend to use this for my [instructions](https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Tokens) on adding tokens - which in the case of joomla says the url construction should be like

Joomla!: http://www.myorganization.org/index.php?option=com_civicrm&task=civicrm/profile/edit&reset=1&gid=N&{contact.checksum}&id={contact.contact_id}

Comment: Thank you pete! This was what I needed. I'll see about reporting the error on the wiki documentation where I got the original url.

Comment: Thank you for 'accepting' the answer. It helps StackExchange if you also +1 it as that indicates the answer was useful.

Answer (score 1):

This is a token substitution error - the information is getting replaced but with the wrong thing.

Next steps are to check out error logs, in a file called ConfigAndLog.

Good luck, report back with what you find.